# Ansible loop lookup issue

Tags: variables, ansible, lookup

I'm trying to install apache http from source and using the following compilation command, which results in mentioned error. Any help please?

```
   - name: Install Apache, Version n -- {{ apache_version }})
     command: "{{ item }} chdir={{ apache_source_dir }}"
     with_items:
        - >
          ./configure --with-apr={{ apr-dir }} --with-apr-util={{ apr_util_dir }}
          --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-ssl --enable-so
          --with-pcre={{ pcre_dir}}/pcre-config --prefix={{ apache_install_dir }}`
        - /usr/bin/make
        - /usr/bin/make install
     become: yes
```

Error:

```
TASK [Install Apache, Version n -- 2.4.43)] ***************************************************
fatal: [physoaapp03-tst]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string (./configure --with-apr={{ apr-dir }} --with-apr-util={{ apr_util_dir }}  --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-ssl --enable-so  --with-pcre={{ pcre_dir}}/pcre-config --prefix={{ apache_install_dir }}`\n).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'StrictUndefined' and 'StrictUndefined'"}
```

Can anyone let me know where do i need to improve in code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like
>   '-'

The error already describes the issue and how to resolve it.

Change `{{ apr-dir }}` to `{{ apr_dir }}` and so on. Change the declaration too.

Please go through the [documentation regarding variable names in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) to avoid this type of problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator for adding the link.